# Flatten nested json into multiple rows

Tags: python, json

I am working on a heavily nested json file that contains multiple dictionaries and lists. Some of the keys are similar and I am wondering if I can put each dictionary into different row. It doesn't matter, if some columns are not the same, the values can be left blank.

Json file (in similar form to the original)

```
{
  "ID": "01",
  "session": [
    {
      "A": [
        "abc",
        "cde",
        "efj"
      ],
      "B": 14,
      "C": 14,
      "D": [
        {
          "F": {
            "a": "ldjf",
            "b": "kdj",
            "ID": "01",
            "c": "kjasgfk",
            "d": [
              "pw"
            ],
            "e": "dsg"
          }
        },
        {
          "F": {
            "a": "ldjewiorf",
            "ID": "01",
            "c": "kjasnbgfk",
            "d": "mbxzc" ,             
            "e": "dsg"
          }
        },
        {
          "F": {
            "f": "1232",
            "g": "rege",
            "h": "en-gb",
            "i": "dfkj34",
            "j": "iyt658"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "AA":"esg",
        "BB": "skdjghk",
        "CC": "adfkh",
        "DD": "sdlkfh"
      }
    },
    {
      "A": [
       "abc",
        "cde",
        "efj"
      ],
      "B": 16,
      "C": 14,
      "D": [
        {
          "F": {
            "a": "sdg",
            "b": "sg",
            "ID": "01",
            "c": "sg",
            "d": "shfh",
            "e": "weitu"
          }
        },
        {
          "F": {
            "f": "1232",
            "m": "sdg",
            "n": "en-sdg",
            "o": "eqe",
            "p": "sdg"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "AA":"ekjhsg",
        "BB": "skkldjghk",
        "CC": "adfyurkh",
        "DD": "sdlkfmlh"
      }
    }
  ],
  "G": {
    "A1": {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 5,
      "dayOfMonth": 1,
      "hourOfDay": 0,
      "minute": 0,
      "second": 0
    },
    "A2": "ksjdf",
    "A3": "s38764",
    "A4": [
      {
        "year": 2016,
        "month": 5,
        "dayOfMonth": 1,
        "hourOfDay": 0,
        "minute": 0,
        "second": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried this code, but puts the whole file in 1 row with multiple columns:

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
             out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out
```

Is there a solution of what I am trying to do or is it impossible?

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: Any luck finding a script for this?